# SEVERE: null java.io.EOFException Can't read values twice from ObjectInputStream in Java

Tags: java, object, client-server, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to read values send from client on server. First time it works fine but reading again gives an Exception.

### client code:

```
String extension=getFileExtension(file);
OutputStream out;
out = socket.getOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
oout.writeObject(extension);
```

### Server Code

```
String extension="";
InputStream in;
in = socket.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream iin = new ObjectInputStream(in);//It gives exception here second time in same running the program
extension = (String)iin.readObject();
```

Comment: Print stack trace for exception in your question, also provide more context.

Comment: i updated can you recheck please..... what i added in the server section in comment

Comment: From the title it seems like you are trying to read the `InputStream` twice. Either do it once or copy to `byte[]` and read that twice. But there's too little in the question to make much sense of anything.

Comment: You haven't updated the question with the stack trace like I suggested. There isn't enough information here to answer you're question.